# Export objects from microsoft visual studio locals list

Tags: c#, object, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I want to make an extension for visual studio in which i could view locals in separate window, the way i want it to look like.
How do i access the locals section? Which service should I use?
Thanks,

Comment: why serialize the objects in the code?

Comment: @lomed didn't get what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Nick Chernuhaha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5697165/nick-chernuha), you can view any objects in C#, XML, or JSON format using [Object Exporter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter).

Comment: That's not an answer/ suggestion. If you would like to do some manipulations on those objects, you can't do it with this extension and that's why I build my own

Comment: You can edit the variable in the quickwatch window, or view it in any of C#, XML, or JSON formats using Object Explorer.   I'm not sure what else you could want.  Why do you hate editing variables in the quickwatch window?

Comment: The idea was to make a semi- automatic that can handle large amount of data (lets say a vector with 10k values) and project them to a graphic.

Comment: nice extension, ty